Amazon Seller API OAuth Issue
I am working on building software to track any Amazon product listing related changes for any store or a user, and alert them. I am facing issues setting up authorization for Amazon seller API in my app. I am building this on a no-code platform called bubble.io. What set of credentials am I supposed to use for this authorization? What URL should I send the user to for authorization, and what should be the scopes in it? Do I need to use the web app credentials from the generic developer console page or I need to use the credentials from the developer console in the seller central? Currently I am using below URL to send the user for authorization:
https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa?client_id=amzn1.application-oa2-client.18254efcd1ef40ecb7f0e54c979c479f&response_type=code&state=oauth123&redirect_uri=https://hijacker.bubbleapps.io/version-test&scope=sellingpartnerapi::notifications
When I add multiple scopes, it gives me 400 Bad Request error.
I want to include multiple scopes:

sellingpartnerapi::listings – For managing product listings.
sellingpartnerapi::products – For retrieving product details.
sellingpartnerapi::notifications – For subscribing to notifications.
sellingpartnerapi::orders – For retrieving order details.
sellingpartnerapi::reports – For requesting and retrieving reports.
sellingpartnerapi::feeds – For submitting feeds.
sellingpartnerapi::inventory – For managing inventory.
sellingpartnerapi::finances – For accessing financial information.
sellingpartnerapi::fba_inbound – For managing inbound shipments.
sellingpartnerapi::fba_inventory – For accessing Fulfillment by Amazon (FBA) inventory.
sellingpartnerapi::merchant_fulfillment – For creating shipments using the Merchant Fulfillment Network.

Developer Console Web Settings Credentials

Seller Central Credentials

I have tried using multiple scopes in request like:
https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa?client_id=amzn1.application-oa2-client.ed333d81a7d34ff1b84982ff1962acb9&scope=sellingpartnerapi::orders%20sellingpartnerapi::products&response_type=code&state=oauth123&redirect_uri=https://hijacker.bubbleapps.io/version-test
But this doesn't work as well and gives me invalid scope error.
